# Expand string into keyword

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am writing a program which was a `struct` with a need to store information on what type it's holding. The data is represented inside the the struct as a pointer to void. A short example of what I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    void *data;
    char *type;
};

int main() {
    struct foo bar = {{'a', 'b', 'c'}, "char"};
    printf("%s\n", (STRING_TO_TYPE(bar.type))bar.data);
    return 0;
}
```

I need an implementation of the `STRING_TO_TYPE` macro that will replace `"char"` with `char`. All of this can be evaluated at compile time for the needs of my program.
What I want to do is hold an object of *any* type, so using an `enum` or checking for string equality will not work.

Comment: Don't think you can use the preprocessor for string comparison.

Comment: C is statically typed. You should use a dynamically typed language for that. Or use a different approach. Note that you shoud not use `void *` where avoidable. For your application, a union would be the better approach. And use an `enum` for the type.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: At least not in a macro.

Comment: This looks like an XY-problem. Provide more information what you _actually_ want to accomplish and we might give better help.

Comment: If you store three chars behind a *void** with no other information as to interpret the pointer as *char**, how do you know later on in your program it's 3? (and not 1 or 1000)

Comment: @tofro: Please use _markup_!

Comment: @tofro In the actual program, I have a variable `size` in the `struct`, which keeps track of how many items are in it.

Comment: @Olaf It is not our position to determine which language he should use or why he is doing it with this one. Our position here is to answer his question.

Comment: A preprocessor macro might be made to work with a static example like this one, but not with a dynamic one where the compiler wouldn't see at compile time what type it is actually handling (Which seems to be your intent, as the static case doesn't make much sense to me). You will most probably need to refer to a big `switch` handling all the types.

Comment: @Olaf You stated "C is statically typed. You should use a dynamically typed language for that.", etc.

Comment: @Rob: Ah, that one! Well, simply: what OP wants to do can just not be done in C. Thus he'd need a different language to do this. That is not recommending to use a different language,. but a fact. Note that the "etc." provides a commonly used alternative approach for C. If you feel my comment out of the rules, feel free to flag, but don't read an implication from my comments I did not state that way.

Comment: The preprocessor can't do anything with the values of variables. It runs before the program runs, so variables don't have values yet. Macros can only transform the source code. So it's impossible for `(STRING_TO_TYPE(bar.type))` to turn into `(char)`.

Comment: BTW, even if you could do it, you forgot the null terminator on your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it is not possible. Not your way. Macros can produce tokens (keywords, if you like), but cannot convert strings to them.

That said, if the thing you are after is really

1. Being able to define a `struct` with a "type" of its `void *` somewhere in the code,
2. Being able to access that type as a keyword from the `struct`'s name,

then you will most likely end up with `typeof`. It is a GNU [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html), so it will only work in GCC, but it works.

In the example code here, you define your `struct` of a certain "type" with the MYSTRUCT macro and get the type using the TYPE macro. The __COUNTER__ [predefined macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) prevents type redefining (each `struct` is its own type, see `gcc -E`) and three macro levels for MYSTRUCT are there for proper stringification of it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define TYPE(x) typeof(x.type)

#define MYSTRUCT(name, type) MYSTRUCT_INTER(name, type, __COUNTER__)

#define MYSTRUCT_INTER(name, type, counter) MYSTRUCT_RAW(name, type, counter)

#define MYSTRUCT_RAW(xName, xType, xCounter) \
    struct mystruct_## xCounter { \
        void * data; \
        xType type; \
    } xName

int main(void) {
    MYSTRUCT(foo, int);
    foo.data = (void *)42;

    TYPE(foo) tmp = foo.data;    /* <-- Here, tmp is an int */
    printf("%d\n", tmp);

    MYSTRUCT(bar, int*);
    bar.data = &tmp;

    TYPE(bar) tmp2 = bar.data;    /* <-- Here, tmp2 is an int* */
    printf("%p\n", tmp2);

    MYSTRUCT(baz, char*);
    baz.data = "Hello world";
    printf("%s\n", (TYPE(baz))baz.data);
    /* ^Expands to (char *)   baz.data */
}
```

Note that I still need to know the `struct`'s "type" to determine `printf()`'s format code, but solving this was not asked.

Don't forget to compile with `-std=gnu**` (you need it for `typeof`)

Comment: Because you can make anonymous `struct` types, you don't need all three macros. You can just do: `#define MYSTRUCT(name, _type) struct { void *data; _type type; } name;`.